# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError in Users#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a NoMethodError in Users#new in the view of users controller. Here is the view:

```
<h1>new</h1>
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :username %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :email %> <br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :password %> <br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

This is placed in app/views/users/new.html.erb
Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def new
    @user = User.new
 end
end
```

This is my route:

```
      signup GET    /signup(.:format)            users#new
```

Error:

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f22fe85bb00>:0x007f22fe827058>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added a custom URL Helper for `/signup` i.e. `signup_path`.

You need to specify that in `form` tag:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to supply the URL to `form_for` as you're not using conventional resources.

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
new_user_path
```

But if use

```
rake routes
```

in command line or browse to a page that does not exists, you will see the list of paths registered.

Hope it helps